# Getting local file in iOS using react native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to grab an audio file that's been saved *locally* and upload using firebase. I've tried using `react-native-fetch-blob` as follows:

`import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'`

`const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs`

but I'm getting the error:

`Error: file not exists`

Even though I'm using the same path I get back after storing the file. So I have:

`console.log('Full path is ' + fullPath) // Gives /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2446[...]E1A9/Documents/myfile.mp4`

but then I when I try

`fs.readFile(RNFetchBlob.wrap(fullPath), 'base64').then((data) => ...`

I get the "file not exists" error.

Does someone have example code of reading a (binary) file as a blob and using it, especially to upload to firebase storage? All of the examples I've found are grabbing the file from an external URL.

Comment: I got the same error.. using a React Native image picker and trying to upload to Firebase with RNFetchBlob.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS platform the directory path will be changed every time you access to the file system. So if you need read file on iOS, you need to get dir path first and concat file name with it.

```
// fileUri is a string like "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B754FAA-2588-4FEC-B0F7-6D890B7B4681/Documents/filename"
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  let arr = fileUri.split('/')
  const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
  filePath = `${dirs.DocumentDir}/${arr[arr.length - 1]}`
} else {
  filePath = audioDataUri
}
```